# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed X, placement implies Y

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, valueerror

I have a timeseries dateframe ranging from 1967 up until present day that gives me the Adjusted Closing price for a given stock. I'm only interested in the prices from Jan 1st, 2020 up May of this year so I sliced this using `.loc`. I want to normalize these prices over this period so I'm using the following formula to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df.loc['2020-01-01':]
df

Date             Ticker         Adj Close
2020-01-02         ABC              X1
2020-01-03         ABC              X2
2020-01-04         ABC              X3
2020-01-05         ABC              X4
2020-01-06         ABC              X5
    ...            ...              ...
2021-05-28         ABC              X355

def normalized(series):
    minimum = df['Adj Close'].min()
    maximum = df['Adj Close'].max()
    return ((df['Adj Close'] - minimum) / (maximum - minimum))

df['Prices Normalized'] = df['Adj Close'].transform(normalized)
```

When I run this though, I get `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 355, placement implies 1`

My goal is to create a new column with the normalized prices, but can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `df['Prices Normalized'] = normalize(pd.Series())`. It looks like `series` doesn't do anything inside your `normalized` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try pipe.  Reason why you getting this error is that transform applies to the series element-wise.  So you get 355 items returned and you try to fit into a column.  By using apply, you are doing for the whole series.

```
def normalized(series):
    minimum = df['Adj Close'].min()
    maximum = df['Adj Close'].max()
    return ((df['Adj Close'] - minimum) / (maximum - minimum))

df['Prices Normalized'] = df['Adj Close'].pipe(normalized)
```

|  | Date | Ticker | Adj Close | Prices Normalized |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-02 | ABC | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | ABC | 2 | 0.25 |
| 2 | 2020-01-04 | ABC | 3 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 2020-01-05 | ABC | 4 | 0.75 |
| 4 | 2020-01-06 | ABC | 5 | 1 |

You can do the following experiment:

```
def p(x):
    print('1')
    
print('pipe')
x = df['Adj Close'].pipe(p)
print('transform')
x = df['Adj Close'].transform(p)
```

[image]

You can further amend the p function to print the contents sent to it:

```
def p(x):
    print(type(x))
    
print('pipe')
x = df['Adj Close'].pipe(p)
print('transform')
x = df['Adj Close'].transform(p)
```

You will see that pipe argument is a series, while transform argument is an int (5 times for my df).

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, you can just apply the function to the whole series as Quang Hoang has shown in the comment.

Comment: @Alfredo Di Massimo. Hi !  If this answers your question, kindly check the tick to accept the answer,. Thanks.